# Stanford coreNLP : can a word in a sentence be part of multiple Coreference chains

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

The question is in the title. Using Stanford's NLP coref module, I am wondering if a given word can be part of multiple coreference chains. Or can it only be part of one chain. 
Could you give me examples of when this might occur.

Similarly, can a word be part of multiple coreference mentions, or only one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word can be part of multiple coreference mentions. Consider for example the mention "the new acquisition by Microsoft". In this case, there are two candidates for mentions: *the new acquisition by Microsoft* and *Microsoft*.

From this example it also follows that a word can be part of multiple coreference chains.